# siunitx: Detecting \mathversion{sans}

Tags: siunitx

Is there a way to tell siunitx to use the `\mathversion{sans}` font in the following example?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{helvet}
 \renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
 \usepackage{sansmath}
 \usepackage{siunitx}
 \begin{document}
 \mathversion{sans} 
  $1=1 \SI{1}{\meter}$

\end{document}
```

(`\sisetup{mode=text}` is cheating).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not a 'detection' issue here: the problem is some code `siunitx` uses to try to avoid 'accidentally' making things bold. Try for example

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{helvet}
 \renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
 \usepackage{sansmath}
 \usepackage{siunitx}
 \makeatletter
 \newcommand{\mymathversion}[1]{%
   \mathversion{#1}%
   \def\unboldmath{%
     \@nomath\unboldmath
     \mathversion{#1}%
   }%
 }
 \makeatother
 \begin{document}
 \mymathversion{sans}
  $1=1 \SI{1}{\meter}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it was quite bewildering that siunitx insisted to use a roman font ;-).

Comment: In version 3 `\SI[reset-math-version=false]{1}{\meter}` seems to work ;-)