# Typeset siunitx-like percentage value in math mode

Tags: spacing, siunitx

I'd like to typeset "10 %" with exactly the same spacing between 10 and % as in `\SI{10}{\percent}`. For [some reason](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/164249/8057) I'd rather not use `siunitx` in this particular instance. How do I replicate the spacing?

- `$10 \%$` is typeset without a space
- `$10~\%$` uses too much space

The `siunitx` documentation explains that the `number-unit-product` option can be used to tweak spacing for new units, but doesn't mention the default value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is very close to a `\,` space:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\showoutput

\SI{10}{\percent}

\( 10\,\% \)
\end{document}
```

shows that the SI command gives a space of `1.66672` whereas the `\,` produces `1.66663` points.