# Incompatibility of siunitx and sansmath?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, siunitx

I seem to have stumbled upon an inconsistency when using both `siunitx` and `sansmath` - I need to have the same expressions in roman and sans-serif fonts.

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{sansmath}  %% first without sansmath
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-all=true}
\begin{document}
  Roman: $F_1=\SI{12.34}{kt/m^{3}}$ (outside math mode: \SI{12.34}{kt/m^{3}})
  \bigskip

  \sffamily  sffamily:
  $F_1=\SI{12.34}{kt/m^{3}}$ (outside math mode: \SI{12.34}{kt/m^{3}})
  \bigskip

  %\sansmath plus sansmath:
  %$F_1=\SI{12.34}{kt/m^{3}}$ (outside math mode: \SI{12.34}{kt/m^{3}})
\end{document}
```

I get the following result:
[image]

So indeed, `siunitx` detects the sf-ness (and there is no difference when using math mode). However, the `F_1` is still roman.

But if I uncomment the sansmath package, like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sansmath}  %% first without sansmath
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-all=true}
\begin{document}
  Roman: $F_1=\SI{12.34}{kt/m^{3}}$ (outside math mode: \SI{12.34}{kt/m^{3}})
  \bigskip

  \sffamily  sffamily:
  $F_1=\SI{12.34}{kt/m^{3}}$ (outside math mode: \SI{12.34}{kt/m^{3}})
  \bigskip

  \sansmath plus sansmath:
  $F_1=\SI{12.34}{kt/m^{3}}$ (outside math mode: \SI{12.34}{kt/m^{3}})
\end{document}
```

the result becomes
[image]
So now `siunitx` typesets the numbers, but not the letters in the unit, in roman font, even before `\sansmath` is used (or if it is not used at all), but not when called without math mode!  Redefining `math-rm=\mathsf` and the like did not work for me.

As a workaround I could use e.g. `$F_1=12.34\,\si{kt/m^{3}}$`, but that screws up some of the nice features of `siunitx` (e.g. spacing and automatic change of decimal sign), and the exponent `3` in the unit is still roman. Is there anything smarter, such as a suitable font redefinition?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: For the last example see here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164249/siunitx-detecting-mathversionsans (\sansmath is internally simply \mathversion{sans}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, that solved it - thanks! (I didn't even know the \mathversion command.)

Comment: @Toffomat This solves it for the example, but actually \sansmath does a bit more (try out some variables to see the problem). I will add an answer in a few minutes.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Indeed it seems to be more complicated -- I had to use \mymathversion{sans}\sansmath  in my real document, but then it works...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`sansmath` changes the type of the numbers from "mathalpha" to "mathord". This means that numbers no longer change their font in `\mathXX` commands and so the internal `\mathsf` from siunitx has no effect on the numbers.

There is no easy work-around: changing the type back to mathalpha would help siunitx but break all other numbers in equations (they would be slanted now). Using a text font in siunitx doesn't work either -- one get problems with superscript. Imho the only thing one can do is that to load `sansmath` only if one is also willing to use it, that means to issue a `\sansmath` (with a small correction):

```
\documentclass[parskip=half-]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{sansmath}  %% first without sansmath

\usepackage{siunitx,amsmath}

\sisetup{detect-all}

 \makeatletter
 \newcommand{\mysansmath}{%
   \def\unboldmath{%
     \@nomath\unboldmath
     \sansmath%
   }%
 }
 \makeatother

\begin{document}
 \minisec{math commands don't work on numbers}

 $\mathsf{123456abc}$  $\mathbf{123456abc}$ $\mathit{123456abc}$

 \minisec{sansmath}

 \sansmath plus sansmath:
  $F_1=\SI{12.34e2}{kt/m^{3}}$


 \mysansmath plus mysansmath:
  $F_1=\SI{12.34e2}{kt/m^{3}}$ 

  outside math mode: \SI{12.34e2}{kt/m^{3}}

  \sffamily

 outside math mode: \SI{12.34e2}{kt/m^{3}}

\end{document}
```

[image]